# Who or what sent the Orb back in time in "Brisco County Jr."?

Tags: tv, brisco-county-jr

Who or what sent the mysterious golden Orb back in time in the Bruce Campbell TV series *[Brisco County Jr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Brisco_County,_Jr).*?

[image: The Orb]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Karina** - From the year 5502, she comes back to help Brisco change history and stop Bly. She can help, but she can't directly influence the past. She is one of the people who created the orbs. Played by Melanie Smith
>
> **The Orbs** - A man-made electromagnetic wave particle net that captures energy at certain nodal intersections of the space-time grid. The Orbs were created in 5502 and sent back in time to aid the advancement of mankind. They are the key to the future and to possess them is to rule the world. John Bly lives only to posses them. Professor Ogden Coles calls them faith. One was called an Unearthed Foreign Object (UFO) when it is unearthed by chinese rail workers. These mysterious objects display the power to give men great strength and heal the wounded but can be lethal if used improperly. The first orb is lost down a river when Big Smith takes it bridge diving from a speeding train. The final two Orbs are taken back to the future by Karina.
>
> **Episodes:** Pilot, Bye Bly.

From: [The Ultimate Adventures of Brisco County](http://theoasis.com/brisco/encyclopedia/encyclopedia.php#orb)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the first Orb resurfaced, along with Big Smith, in the episode 'Crystal Hawks', where it was revealed to be in the hands of federal agents, who disappeared with the Orb during Brisco's fight with John Bly. That same Orb would next appear in the episode 'AKA Kansas' where it was being kept at a secret location. John Bly made an attempt to steal that Orb during a sneak attack, but he was defeated by Brisco & escaped. Brisco was about to take possession of the Orb when another Brisco arrived from the future (actually from the episode 'Bye Bly') & took the Orb with him. The only Orb that was truly lost was the one that was destroyed in the episode 'Senior Spirit'. That Orb had previously been damaged (presumably when it fell to Earth from space, as it was noted by Brisco's friend Professor Wickwire that the scorching on that Orb was similar to that found on meteors) & exploded shortly after the Orb rod that was missing from it was put back in place. The Orbs that Karina took back with her to the future were the Orb that the federal agents had taken from Big Smith & the Orb that Professor Coles had had in his possession until the episode 'Fountain of Youth'.